# TOP Returning null

Tags: sql, null

I have the following view below.  The second nested select is always returning null when I use the TOP(1) clause, but when I remove this clause it returns the data as expected, just more rows than is needed.  Does anyone see anything that would explain this?

```
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    a.ITEMID AS Model
   ,id.CONFIGID
   ,id.INVENTSITEID AS SiteId
   ,id.INVENTSERIALID AS Serial
   ,it.ITEMNAME AS Description
   ,CASE WHEN it.DIMGROUPID LIKE '%LR-Y' THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
    END AS SerialNumberReqd
   ,ISNULL(it.PRIMARYVENDORID, N'') AS Vendor
   ,ISNULL(vt.NAME, N'') AS VendorName
   ,id.INVENTLOCATIONID AS Warehouse
   ,id.WMSLOCATIONID AS Bin
   ,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(12), CASE WHEN C.DatePhysical < '1901-01-01'
                                     THEN NULL
                                     ELSE C.DatePhysical
                                END, 101), N' ') AS DeliveryDate
   ,CASE WHEN (a.RESERVPHYSICAL > 0
               OR C.StatusIssue = 1)
              AND c.TransType = 0 THEN C.PONumber
         ELSE ''
    END AS SoNumber
   ,'' AS SoDetail
   ,ISNULL(C.PONumber, N'') AS RefNumber
   ,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(12), CASE WHEN ins.ProdDate < '1901-01-01'
                                     THEN NULL
                                     ELSE ins.PRODDATE
                                END, 101), N' ') AS DateReceived
   ,it.STKSTORISGROUPID AS ProdGroup
   ,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(12), CASE WHEN ins.ProdDate < '1901-01-01'
                                     THEN NULL
                                     ELSE ins.PRODDATE
                                END, 101), N' ') AS ProductionDate
   ,it.ITEMGROUPID
   ,it.STKSTORISGROUPID AS MerchandisingGroup
   ,CASE WHEN a.postedValue = 0
         THEN (CASE WHEN D.CostAmtPosted = 0 THEN D.CostAmtPhysical
                    ELSE D.CostAmtPosted
               END)
         ELSE a.POSTEDVALUE
    END AS Cost
   ,CASE WHEN a.PHYSICALINVENT = 0 THEN a.Picked
         ELSE a.PhysicalInvent
    END AS PhysicalOnHand
   ,ins.STKRUGSQFT AS RugSqFt
   ,ins.STKRUGVENDSERIAL AS RugVendSerial
   ,ins.STKRUGVENDDESIGN AS RugVendDesign
   ,ins.STKRUGEXACTSIZE AS RugExactSize
   ,ins.STKRUGCOUNTRYOFORIGIN AS RugCountryOfOrigin
   ,ins.STKRUGQUALITYID AS RugQualityId
   ,ins.STKRUGCOLORID AS RugColorId
   ,ins.STKRUGDESIGNID AS RugDesignId
   ,ins.STKRUGSHAPEID AS RugShapeId
   ,CASE WHEN (a.AVAILPHYSICAL > 0) THEN 'Available'
         WHEN (id.WMSLOCATIONID = 'NIL') THEN 'Nil'
         WHEN (a.RESERVPHYSICAL > 0)
              AND (c.TransType = 0) THEN 'Committed'
         WHEN (a.RESERVPHYSICAL > 0) THEN 'Reserved'
         WHEN (id.WMSLOCATIONID LIKE '%-Q') THEN 'Damaged'
         WHEN (a.Picked > 0) THEN 'Picked'
         ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END AS Status
   ,'' AS ReasonCode
   ,'' AS BaseModel
   ,ISNULL(CAST(ins.STKSTORISCONFIGINFO AS nvarchar(1000)), N'') AS StorisConfigInfo
   ,ISNULL(C.ConfigSummary, N'') AS ConfigSummary
FROM
    dbo.INVENTSUM AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTDIM AS id WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON id.DATAAREAID = a.DATAAREAID
       AND id.INVENTDIMID = a.INVENTDIMID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS it WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON it.DATAAREAID = a.DATAAREAID
       AND it.ITEMID = a.ITEMID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VENDTABLE AS vt WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON vt.DATAAREAID = it.DATAAREAID
       AND vt.ACCOUNTNUM = it.PRIMARYVENDORID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTSERIAL AS ins WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ins.DATAAREAID = id.DATAAREAID
       AND ins.INVENTSERIALID = id.INVENTSERIALID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP (1)
                    itt.ITEMID
                   ,invt.INVENTSERIALID
                   ,itt.DATEPHYSICAL AS DatePhysical
                   ,itt.TRANSREFID AS PONumber
                   ,itt.TRANSTYPE AS TransType
                   ,itt.STATUSISSUE AS StatusIssue
                   ,dbo.stkRowsToColumn(itt.INVENTTRANSID, 'STI') AS ConfigSummary
                   ,itt.RECID
                 FROM
                    dbo.INVENTTRANS AS itt WITH (NOLOCK)
                 INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTDIM AS invt WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON invt.DATAAREAID = itt.DATAAREAID
                       AND invt.INVENTDIMID = itt.INVENTDIMID
                 WHERE
                    (itt.DATAAREAID = 'STI')
                    AND (itt.TRANSTYPE IN (0, 2, 3, 8))
                    AND (invt.INVENTSERIALID <> '')
                 ORDER BY
                    itt.RECID DESC) AS C
    ON C.ITEMID = a.ITEMID
       AND C.INVENTSERIALID = id.INVENTSERIALID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP (1)
                    itt2.ITEMID
                   ,invt2.INVENTSERIALID
                   ,itt2.COSTAMOUNTPOSTED AS CostAmtPosted
                   ,itt2.COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL + itt2.COSTAMOUNTADJUSTMENT AS CostAmtPhysical
                   ,itt2.RECID
                 FROM
                    dbo.INVENTTRANS AS itt2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                 INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTDIM AS invt2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON invt2.DATAAREAID = itt2.DATAAREAID
                       AND invt2.INVENTDIMID = itt2.INVENTDIMID
                 WHERE
                    (itt2.DATAAREAID = 'STI')
                    AND (itt2.TRANSTYPE IN (0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8))
                    AND (invt2.INVENTSERIALID <> '')
                 ORDER BY
                    itt2.RECID DESC) AS D
    ON D.ITEMID = a.ITEMID
       AND D.INVENTSERIALID = id.INVENTSERIALID
WHERE
    (a.DATAAREAID = 'STI')
    AND (a.CLOSED = 0)
    AND (a.PHYSICALINVENT > 0)
    AND (it.ITEMGROUPID LIKE 'FG-%'
         OR it.ITEMGROUPID = 'MULTISHIP')
ORDER BY
    SiteId
   ,Warehouse
```

Comment: I feel like such a noob saying this but the SQL editor keeps forcing them when I try to remove them.  I'll see if I can work around it though.

Comment: @Michael stop using the view designer and it will stop formatting your code so badly and re-writing things for you.

Comment: Also, please stop adding TOP (100) PERCENT and ORDER BY to the view (again, you can stop SQL Server from doing this for you by not using the buggy view designer in the first place). These clauses have absolutely no meaning and are literally thrown away by the optimizer.

Comment: One more thing, you have `LEFT OUTER JOIN ... AS it` and then `WHERE it.something`. This effectively translates your left join into an inner join, which is probably not what you expected. Try moving that last where clause to the outer join condition for that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the top value in the subquery doesn't meet the subsequent `join` conditions.  That is, this condition is not met:

```
D.ITEMID = a.ITEMID AND D.INVENTSERIALID = id.INVENTSERIALID
```

You are using a `left outer join`, so `NULL` values are filled in.

EDIT:

To re-iterate.  When you run it with `top 1`, there are no values (for at least some combinations of the two variables).  So, `NULL` will be filled in for these values.  After all, `top 1` (with or without the parentheses) returns only one row.

When you run it returning multiple rows, presumably there are matches.  For the rows that match, the corresponding values are put it.  This is the way that `left outer join` works.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but when I run it without the TOP 1, the data is returned as I would expect without any nulls.  It seems just by adding the TOP 1, it returns null.  Also what I've noticed is it doesn't matter what number I put in the TOP clause, it always returns null unless it is completely removed.

Comment: I am following you, but maybe I am missing something still.  When I remove the TOP clause, 19 rows are returned.  In these 19 rows, the ItemId and InventSerial fields match between A and D as seen in the screenshot here http://imgur.com/NCkGZpq.  I would expect to see some values missing according to your reply.

Comment: @MichaelSage . . . When you *remove* the `top` clause, you are getting *all* the rows.  So you are getting matches.  When you have the `top` clause, you are probably only returning a subset of the rows, so you fail to get matches (unless your `top` is large enough to get all the rows).

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is correct as to why I was getting a few rows when removing top and none when I had it.  The subquery in question was returning all the rows in the InventTrans table (5 million+) so when I used top, it was just getting the first row which didn't have anything.  I realized this was the case when I was trying random high values (e.g 50000) in the TOP clause.

The ultimate fix was to change the left outer joins on the C and D subqueries to Cross Apply, and then change the where clauses to better filter the table (e.g itt.itemid = a.itemid and invt1.inventserialid = id.inventserialid).  Using that, I was able to use TOP 1 as expected.